# Blender not rendering a specific object

Tags: cycles-render-engine

It shows up in preview render and solid viewports but refuses to show in final render. I have check every setting I could find that was related to the object and final render as well as the camera icon in the layers

[image: Main Screen in Preview Render]

[image: Final Render]

Comment: Your Skin modifier is disabled for rendering, so it can be an issue ...

Comment: Agree. Try clicking on the Skin modifier's [renderable button](https://i.imgur.com/2U6Qg4u.jpeg) and render again. If it doesn't work, please upload your file on [blend-exchange.com](https://blend-exchange.com/) and share the link here with us so that we can check ourselves.

Comment: thank you so much i've been racking my brain for hours on this xD

Answer (score 1):

The skin modifier itself also has a renderable button just like layers. This was accidentally switched off.